# I've got this error: map.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: event.target.getPosition is not a function at yn.<anonymous> (map.js:33)

Tags: heremaps

It doesn't display me the infobubble popup  and I tried to change the code, on line 33, but it still doesn't work.

```
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    var marker1 = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 47.045299, lng: 21.919435 });
     marker1.setData
(
   "<p> Universitatea din Oradea, Facultatea de Geografie, 
        Turism și Sport <br> Adresa: <br> Nume Masterat:<br> Număr de 
        Studenți: 
  </p > "
);
      marker1.addEventListener("tap", event => {
         var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(
             ***event.target.getPosition(),***
              {
                 content: event.target.getData()
              }
          );
       ui.addBubble(bubble);
    }, false);
```

Comment: Try to use **Developer tools** and add a breakpoint on that line; inspect the `event.target` object - perhaps it's of a different type than you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
event.target.getPosition()
```

Use:

```
event.target.getGeometry();
```